# Android AppCompat Toolbar does not respond to touching action items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

I'm following [these instructions](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) to implement an `AppCompat Toolbar` in my Android app.  I am using AppCompat version 7:22.0.1  Also, I'm using this toolbar in addition to the actionBar (it's not replacing the `ActionBar`, as I see in many other examples).

The toolbar shows up, and it even shows the icon I specificed, but it does not respond when I touch the icon.  Has anyone had a similar problem with the `AppCompat Toolbar`?  Any suggestions on what to try next?

Here's my code from my browse() method in MainActivity.Java:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);

// Set an OnMenuItemClickListener to handle menu item clicks
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle the menu item
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.browse_back_button:
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
                restart(view);
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
});

// Inflate a menu to be displayed in the toolbar
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.toolbar_menu);
```

I placed this snippet of code in the XML layout file, as the first item in a `RelativeLayout` element.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#FFFF00" />
```

The `Toolbar` is inflated from a menu layout xml file.  It consists of a menu element with a single 'item' element :

```
<item android:title="Back"
    android:id="@+id/browse_back_button"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_back"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: Place the toolbar LAST in the layout so it's painted OVER everything. The padding of adjacent ListView is part the ListView and consumes touch events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ListView is drawn on top of the Toolbar view and thus that is the view that will get the touch events. You should place the `Toolbar` as last element in the layout, or you should use a vertical `LinearLayout`, or you should use `android:layout_below`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/listViewBrowse"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="#FFFF00" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="#FFFF00" />

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/listViewBrowse"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:background="#FFFF00" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewBrowse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_awesome_toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would use a `LinearLayout` here, since it is more convenient here. It does what you want to do. Align a view next to, not over, another view.

(EDIT: I see that this was commented already, don't get why. Because it is an answer to the question.)

Comment: I didn't realize LinearyLayout is more convenient here.  It makes sense and it works well.  Thank you.