# Android Toolbar problems with appcompat-v7:22.2.1 NavigationOnClick and windowNoTitle

Tags: android, navigation, toolbar

So there are quite a few posts here on StackOverflow solving the issue of windowNoTitle and NavigationOnClickListener, but all these posts are not working for me. My Activity is supposed to use a Toolbar rather than the default Toolbar to handle back navigation to parent Activity (when clicking on navigation icon). The problem is, with my theme setup and using a custom toolbar, I can't seem to trigger the navigation's click listener...

Here is my toolbar (I use include layout="@layout/toolbar.xml" in my main layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/material_blue"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Here is my Theme in values.xml:

```
<style name="AppThemeBlue"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_green</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/material_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/android:white</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".skeleton.activities.SignupActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_signup"
        android:parentActivityName=".skeleton.activities.StartActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeBlue"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible|stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.thorrism.skeleton.activities.StartActivity" />
    </activity>
```

and code from my activity that uses it:

```
private void setupToolbar(){
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if(mToolbar != null){
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("Test", "test");
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I'm running the following for gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
}
```

First of all, the title is isn't gone and I have tried adding android: as a prefix to windowNoTitle, still doesn't work. And secondly, the navigation icon does not get triggered, even when trying to catch the menu item android.R.id.home in onOptionsItemSelected().

Please help :( This isn't working on my Galaxy S6 if that changes anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the toolbar is not receiving the click events is probably due to it being the first element in the layout i.e

```
<RelativeLayout
   ...
   .../>

   <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

   <LinearLayout
       ...
       .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So what happens is the LinearLayout's top padding is probably drawn over the toolbar. Therefore, the LinearLayout receives the onClick event rather than the toolbar. To fix this, add the toolbar's include to be the very last element in the layout, then it will receive the clicks.

Source: [Android AppCompat Toolbar does not respond to touching action items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087932/android-appcompat-toolbar-does-not-respond-to-touching-action-items)

As to the title still being displayed, even with windowNoTitle, I have no idea why this wouldn't work. A quick solution would be to add:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

A temporary solution until someone else finds out what is wrong :)